# Route all POST requests to a single ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I want all PUT and POST requests to be deserialised to an appropriate command and sent to an end point via a message bus.  I'd rather not have an ApiController per command nor a base controller that implements a generic Put method.

So, is it possible to route all requests for a given verb to a single ApiController, or something appropriate, and still benefit from model binding?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you are looking for are the [HttpGet] and [HttpPost] controller attributes. This allows you to create two methods that differ by this attribute. For example:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(int viewId)
{
    return View(new IndexViewModel(viewId));
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(IndexViewModel model)
{
    model.DoSomethingUsefulWithPostData();
    return View(model);
}
```

The first method will take a query string argument and construct a view model from it. The second will be called upon form post and reconstruct the model, including any values from the POST itself within the model.